# Updating appwidget cause set values to default

Tags: java, android, service, widget, android-widget

I am writing an application widget that takes data from a server and displays them in a appwidget.
The problem is that when there is no internet connection and at this point the system updates the widget, `TextView` text value reset to the default text setted with `android:text="sometext"`

It happens like this:

1. Widget placed on homescreen
2. Internet connection is active
3. Widget successfully updated
4. The text of the response from the server is installed in the `TextView`
5. Internet connection is not active
6. The system updates the widget
7. Previous text in the `TextView` reset to the value setted  in `android:text=""`

I know that somewhere I incorrectly do something, because in other widgets (not my) with no connection to the Internet does not reset.

File **WidgetProvider.java**

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "MYAPPLOG";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate");

        for (int widgetID : appWidgetIds)
        {
            updateWidget(context, widgetID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDeleted");
    }

    public void updateWidget(Context context, int widgetID)
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdatingService.class).putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID));
    }
}
```

File **UpdatingService.java**

```
public class UpdatingService extends IntentService {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "MYAPPLOG";

    public UpdatingService() {
        super("UpdatingService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // getting widgetID from intent and other vars

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                R.layout.initial_layout);

            if(isConnected(getApplicationContext()))
            {
                String response = getServerResponse();

                if(response != null)
                {
                    try {
                        JSONObject JSON = new JSONObject(response);
                        // get data from server
                        // ...
                        // set values to the views
                        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, someText);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "JSONObject failed");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // LOG: error connection to server
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // LOG: No internet connection
            }

        // updating apwidget (set click action for the some button)
        // if not do update then button will not work

        Intent someIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WidgetProvider.class);
        someIntent.setAction(WidgetProvider.ACTION_GOTO);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                widgetID, someIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.goToLayout, pendingIntent);

        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext())
                .updateAppWidget(widgetID, remoteViews);
    }

    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getServerResponse() {
        // using HttpURLConnection
    }
}
```

I hope for your help or a little tip. I wrote several widgets and all with this problem. Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an AppWidget update happens then every property must be set, like all the values of text views, all click listeners, colors, etc. Simply everything. What is not set will use the default value from the layout XML.

In your case you do nothing in the else branch ("no internet") thus your app widget ends up with the default text. So when you fetch the data from the server you must save it and use it the next time there is no internet connection.

Comment: OK, I pasted in `updateWidget(Context context, int widgetID)` before starting service code that setting up the property to textview but it still not working. Every time when system update the widget with no internet connection it set values from xml, even if the values was setted by service on previous time.

Comment: You are creating the app widget's UI in your service i.e. `RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                R.layout.initial_layout);`. That is the code that "resets" the UI. So do not update your `updateWidget(Context context, int widgetID)` method but your ELSE branch in your `Service` with `// LOG: No internet connection`. There you will set the app widget's text to your saved value.

Comment: May be I have to create UI (`RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews`) in a service only one time and only work with this `remoteViews` (do  not create avery when I need the `remoteViews `)?

Comment: That will not work when system/launcher kills the process of your app widget (for whatever reason) and then needs to re-create it. Save the value of your `someText` in `SharedPreferences`, or somewhere, and then load it from it in the "no Internet" else branch. Do not hack the system, just always set all the values that have to be set.